# Covering a set with geometric progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, covering

Consider the set $S_n=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$. What is the minimum number of distinct geometric progressions that cover $S_n$? Let us call this number $a_n$. I was wondering about this number after doing a problem from the Allrussian MO, 1995.

> Can the set $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ be covered with $12$ geometric progressions?

It becomes straightforward after observing the fact no three primes can be in a geometric progression. Hence the problem is restated to the obvious contradiction 
$$\pi(100)\le 24$$
Now I had searched a bit and [here](http://leonettipaolo.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/covering-sets-with-geometric-progressions/) it is proven that $a_{100}\ge 24$. Now I would like some asymptotics, or references, or better bounds on $a_n$ .

> I have also found the fact that $$a_n\ge \left\lfloor{\frac{3n}{\pi^2}}\right\rfloor$$

Which is obvious since any geometric progression contains at most $2$ squarefree numbers and there are about $\dfrac{6n}{\pi^2}$ squarefree numbers less than $n$. Note it surpasses the bound given. But is something better possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean minimum, not maximum.

Comment: Hmmmm thanks I will edit it. I got confused sorry. The rest is clear I hope.

Comment: Are you interested in geometric progressions with *integer* quotients only? Otherwise any two numbers are in a geometric progression, and you immediately get the upper bound of $\lceil n/2\rceil$ (which probably can be improved a bit with some effort, since you can start with progressions covering much more than two elements).

Comment: The $n/2$ upper bound holds even for progressions with integer coefficients: consider progressions with ratio 2 and odd initial values.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understood integer-quotient correctly, but I am also considering GP's which achieve non-integral reals. See the link I gave it assumes the same as me. Is this a bit clear now?

Comment: Now the lower bound is $\frac{3}{\pi^2}n \approx 0.30396n$, and the upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}n = 0.5n$ -- hence we are already quite close.

Comment: You can get the upper bound of $3n/8$ by pairing off odd numbers in $(n/2,n)$.  Then for each odd number below $n/2$ use the geometric progression with ratio $2$ starting from it.

Comment: One can improve the lower bound slightly. Let $S$ be the set of integers which are either square-free or have the form $2^3 3^2 m$, where $m$ is square-free and not divisible by $2$ or $3$. Then $S$ has density $\delta>6/\pi^2$ and still contains no more than two elements in any one geometric progression, so you get $a_n/n\geq \delta/2$. I do not know the maximal density of a subset of $\mathbf{N}$ with no more than two elements in any geometric progression.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard: Nathanson and O'Bryant have shown that this density is at most $\frac{18731}{22050}\approx 0.849$.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard: See also this very recent preprint of Nathan McNew: http://www.nathanmcnew.com/GPFsets.pdf

Comment: @Seva I think neither of these references is directly relevant. Here we're interested in a set with no three terms in *any* geometric progression (say the first, second, and hundredth term), not just no three-term geometric progressions.

Comment: Actually I think these two problems are formally dual, in the sense of linear programming. In one problem we are trying to maximize the value of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ subject to $x_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i\in G} x_i\leq 2$ for every geometric progression $G$, and in the other we are trying to dominate the sum $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ by the sum of a few expressions of the form $\sum_{i\in G} x_i$. The only thing missing from this argument is something about integrality of solutions, but I imagine/hope there is some formal nonsense reason to expect integrality for this system.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4331v1.pdf may also be of some interest.

Comment: If you are interested in the general case for this problem (larger n) then please see my answer on Math StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3291655/420064

Answer (score 9):

We can reduce Lucia's upper bound of $3/8$ a little further as follows. Begin by taking the $n/4$ geometric progressions of common ratio $2$ beginning at each odd number at most $n/2$. Then for each odd number $x$ in the range $[n/2,25n/49]$ divisible by $25$ include the progression $\{x,(7/5)x,(7/5)^2x\}$. Pair off the remaining odd numbers. If I've added this up correctly I get $3/8 - 1/(4900)$ as an upper bound.

As I explained in my comment one can improve the lower bound $3/\pi^2$ slightly by considering a set of integers $S$ larger than just the square-frees but still not containing any three terms of a geometric progression. Here is a somewhat general construction of such a set. Let $Q\subset\mathbf{Z}_{\geq0}^2$ be any set without three points on a line. Now let $p_1,p_2,\dots$ be the primes and let
$$S = \left\{\text{integers }n= \prod p_i^{e_i} \text{ such that } (e_1,e_2)\in Q, (e_3,e_4)\in Q,\dots\right\}.$$
Then $S$ has no three terms of any geometric progression, and one could write down an Euler-product-like expression for the density of $S$ in terms of $Q$. Note if $Q$ contains
$$\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$$
then $S$ contains all square-free integers, but $Q$ could be larger as well. Taking
$$Q = \{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,3)\},$$
the density of $S$ is
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{p_{2i-1}}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{p_{2i}}\right)(1 + p_{2i-1}^{-1} + p_{2i}^{-1} + p_{2i-1}^{-1} p_{2i}^{-1} + p_{2i-1}^{-2} p_{2i}^{-3}),$$
which in any case is bounded below by
$$ \frac{1 + 2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + 2^{-1} 3^{-1} + 2^{-2} 3^{-3}}{1 + 2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + 2^{-1} 3^{-1}} \prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \frac{217}{36\pi^2}.$$
Thus $\frac{217}{72\pi^2}$ is a lower bound.

This problem is mentioned as problem 2014.2.1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3558v2.pdf, though presumably others have pondered it as well.

Comment: You might as well use odd x which are multiples of 25 and are greater than n/4 instead of waiting till n/2.  You can treat other multiples of squares this way as well, especially the odd multiples of 9 greater than n/4 and less than 9n/25.